# How to find and delete media files on device in Android

Tags: android, image, video, android-image, android-video-player

I am creating an app to find and delete media files like video, photo saved on the Android device. I think I should go the way of Intents but I am not sure of the approach.

Could anyone please advise me on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the files with popular media formats like (mpg, avi, 3gp, jpg etc).

Use f.getName().endsWith(".3gp")      //for 3gp, where f is the File object.

Delete these files using f.delete().

Comment: Thanks however I pass a filename as value and use that as the search criteria as well as for deletion if necessary, could you please lay out some code samples? thanks

Comment: public static void parseDir(File dirPath, String ext)
 {
  
  File files[] = null;
  if(dirPath.isDirectory())
  {
   files = dirPath.listFiles();
   for(File dirFiles:files)
   {
    
    if(dirFiles.isDirectory())
    {
     parseDir(dirFiles,ext);
    }
    else
    {
     if(dirFiles.getName().endsWith(ext))
     {
      dirFiles.delete();
     }
    }
   }
   
  }
  else
  {
   if(dirPath.getName().endsWith(ext))
   {
    dirPath.delete();
   }
  }
  
 }  

 //Using parseDir(new File("D:/Shashank/Test/"),".txt"); will delete all txt files from directory Test..

Comment: The above function will delete all files with extension "ext" inside folder dirPath.

Comment: once after deleting make sure you invoke the mediascanner or delete the particular file from MediaContentProvider.

Comment: Does anyone actually have code sample related to MediaContentProvider?

Comment: see if this helps....http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-display-thumbnails-of-images.html